# Adding some text in the page containing the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

How to add some text somewhere (middle and at a given distance say 3cm above of the beginning of the table of contents) at the top of the page containing the `Table of contents`?

Something like the image below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\title{hello}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{one}
\chapter{two}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, `\tableofcontents` uses a `\chapter*` heading in `book`, i.e. the heading formatter macro `\@makeschapterhead` has to be slightly modified, and an injection of an 'arbitrary' `\mytextbeforetocheading` command to executed.

In order to restrict the modifications to this `toc` only (and not affecting any further `\chapter*`), all has to be done a group.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand{\mytextbeforetocheading}{%
  \begingroup
  \centering%
  \Huge  \bfseries Some Text

  \endgroup
  \vskip3\baselineskip% 
}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\tableofcontents}{%
  \chapter%
}{%
  \begingroup
   \def\@makeschapterhead##1{%
    \vspace*{50\p@}%
    \mytextbeforetocheading%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
      \normalfont
      \interlinepenalty\@M
      \Huge \bfseries  ##1\par\nobreak
      \vskip 40\p@
    }}
  \chapter%
}{\typeout{success}}{\typeout{failure}}
\xapptocmd{\tableofcontents}{\endgroup}{}{} % Close the group
\makeatother

\title{hello}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{one}
\chapter{two}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We can exploit the fact that `\tableofcontents` basically does `\chapter*{\contentsname}` and that `\chapter` begins with issuing `\cleardoublepage` (unless we're in a two column document). So we ensure being on an odd page, open a group and redefine `\clearpage` (that's called by `\cleardoublepage` to simply end the group we opened.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\begin{document}

% ensure we're on an odd page
\cleardoublepage
% open a group for doing local redefinitions
\begingroup
% a \clearpage will close the group and restore the meaning
\let\clearpage\endgroup

% here you type the text you want 
\begin{center}
Some text before the table of contents
\end{center}
% Now issue \tableofcontents

\tableofcontents
\chapter{one}
\chapter{two}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Name: Instead of saying `Thank you` you could accept one of the solutions ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have always done so. But not not necessarily immediately.