# Adding a small text manually for word count at the bottom of table of contents page for a thesis

Tags: table-of-contents

For my PhD thesis, I need to mention the word count at the bottom of the table of contents page. Here is an small minimal working example of my latex file.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,onecolumn,hidelinks]{report}

\begIn{document}

\begin{titlepage}
....
\end{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures % makes a list of figures
\listoftables  % uncomment this if you have tables

\newpage

\chapter{Introduction}
.....


\end{document}
```

Is there a possible way to manually add a small text at the bottom of the toc page? I have provided an image to make the query a little clearer. Thanks. [image]

Comment: `\tableofcontents\vfill Word count: ...\listoffigures`?

Comment: Maybe [Adding some text in the page containing the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273907/124842). And add `\tableofcontents` before `\begingroup`.